# Zombie story about everyone dying simultaneously & reanimating?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, zombie

Looking for a short story that was published about 2017 in an anthology (English language, probably ebook only) of zombie stories.

Plot: main character is an adult man, father and husband, office worker of some kind. For unknown reasons, every human being on Earth dies at the same exact instant, and then immediately re-animates. At first they're confused but fairly normal looking and acting.

Main character goes home to his wife and son. They hole up in the house and try to look online for answers. There are riots going on outside. As time passes they begin to slow down mentally and physically, then go through the stages of decay.

At first they're in denial, trying to appear normal. The son begs to go outside and play, but the man insists everyone stay inside. The chaos outside increases as people freak out.

Eventually the man and his wife sit in their living, slowly rotting away while doing everything they can (cranked AC, not moving) to stay in one piece as long as possible.

The son, however, takes the opportunity to go outside and play in the garden finally. He has a wonderful day, and even though he has hastened his decay, his last thought as he lays looking at the stars is about the fun he had.

Very poignant.